# Minimum Height on a GWT Panel

Tags: gwt, panel

On a GWT panel, can I enforce a minimum height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A GWT Panel is just a `<div>` element. You can use the CSS [`min-height`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_min-height.asp) property to enforce a minimum height for that `div`.

Just use `panel.addStyleName("foo");` on the panel you want to control, and in your CSS, use `.foo { min-height: 100px; }` or whatever you want it to be.

Or if you're using UIBinder:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>>
  <ui:style>
    .foo { min-height: 100px; }
  </ui:style>

  <g:Panel styleName='{style.foo}'>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: Although min-height will work, one has to be careful with its usage as certain older versions of IE do not support it.